# Count amount of lines in unity GUI (break count after each comma)

Tags: c#, string, unity-game-engine, line

I'm creating a rhythm game on Unity and I'm using an external program which in turn gives me 0000,1000,0100,0001 as outputs, and I'm using them to create the song levels. I've come across a problem where sometimes it prints four lines before a comma (a whole beat), and sometimes eight lines before a comma (half beats), and so on. Is there any way I can make Unity detect the  amount of lines before a comma hits? Code & images below; if you need any other parts tell me, thanks !

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEditor;

[CustomEditor(typeof(NoteData))]
public class NoteDataEditor : Editor
{
    public override void OnInspectorGUI()
    {
        base.OnInspectorGUI();

        NoteData data = target as NoteData;
        if (GUILayout.Button("Parse"))
        {
            float x = 60f / data.BPM;

            float currentTime = 0;
            List<NoteData.NoteInfo> notes = new List<NoteData.NoteInfo>();

            string[] allNotes = data.noteSequence.Split('\n');
            foreach (string note in allNotes)
            {
                if (note.Trim() == ",") continue;
                currentTime += x;
                if (note.Trim() == "0000") continue;
                NoteData.NoteColor colorToAdd = NoteData.NoteColor.Red;
                if (note.Trim() == "1000")
                {
                    colorToAdd = NoteData.NoteColor.Green;
                }
                else if (note.Trim() == "0100")
                {
                    colorToAdd = NoteData.NoteColor.Blue;
                }
                else if (note.Trim() == "0010")
                {
                    colorToAdd = NoteData.NoteColor.Red;
                    //colorToAdd = (NoteData.NoteColor) Random.Range(0, 3);
                }

                
                notes.Add(new NoteData.NoteInfo(){
                    color = colorToAdd,
                    timeStamp = currentTime
                });
            }

            data.notes = notes.ToArray();
        }
    }
}
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/zDjSP.png

Answer (score 0):

I managed to find a solution by adding a line counter which puts the counter to 0 whenever a comma is seen, and adds +1 to the counter everytime there isn't a comma until one pops up.